# Cumulative Sum of decision variable as budget constraint (pulp)

Tags: python, optimization, constraints, linear-programming, pulp

My program is **not taking my constraint as desired**.

This is my whole code:

```
    import sys
!{sys.executable} -m pip install pulp
import pulp
import pandas as pd

dates = [d.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') for d in pd.date_range("2020-01-01","2020-12-31")]


days = range(367)
preise = range(367)
capacity = 100000

#Decision variable
volumes = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("volumes", days,
                                 lowBound=-2400, 
                                 upBound=1500, 
                                 cat=pulp.LpContinuous)

#Initialize Problem
storage = pulp.LpProblem("Storage Valuation", pulp.LpMaximize)

#Objective Function
storage += pulp.lpSum([volumes[(i)] * preise[(i)] 
                       for i in days]), "objective function"

for j in days:
    storage += sum(volumes) <= capacity, "capacity constraint {}".format(j)


storage.solve()
print("Status : ", pulp.LpStatus[storage.status])
print("Result : ", pulp.value(storage.objective))
data = []
for v in storage.variables():
    data.append({'wert': v.varValue})
result = pd.DataFrame (data)


result.insert(1, "Storage level", result['wert'].cumsum(), True)
result.insert(2, "Date", dates, True)

with pd.option_context('display.max_rows', None, 'display.max_columns', None):  
    print(result)
```

The cumulative sum of my decision variable is not allowed to exceed a certain capacity at every day.

For the constraint, I have also tried out something like:

```
    for j in days:
    storage += pulp.lpSum([volumes[i][j] for i in days) <= capacity, "Capacity Limit {}".format(j)
```

I believe something is wrong with the lpSum statement. 
Maybe I need something like a counting variable for my program. If so, how do I implement this?

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you pose your question as a [mcve]? Include toy example data and everything else needed to others can hit run, and see the problem you are having. In what way is your constraint not behaving as expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following changes gives a result (although I'm not quite sure this is what you need):

```
#days = range(367)
#preise = range(367)
days = range(366)
preise = range(366)
```

Change the constraints (to limit the cumulative sum):

```
#for j in days:
#    storage += sum(volumes) <= capacity, "capacity constraint {}".format(j)    
for j in days:
    storage += pulp.lpSum([volumes[(i)] for i in range(j+1)]) <= capacity
```

Don't loop over the dictionary, the order of the variables is not guaranteed. Instead:

```
#for v in storage.variables():
#    data.append({'wert': v.varValue})
for j in days:
    data.append({'wert': volumes[(j)].varValue})
```

Comment: Awesome, works really great now!!! Just one question, why does it have to be range(j+1) and not only range(j)? Don't really get this.

Comment: This is to include the j-th volume in the cumulative sum, e.g. on day 0 you want to include day 0 in the sum (range end being non-inclusive).